# Power BI calculate Measure for previous working day

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, business-intelligence

in Power BI I need to write a measure, which returns yesterdays Sales Amount. I can use PREVIOUSDAY() for Tuesday to Friday. However, for Monday I would like to return Friday's Sales Amount. I know I can do this with DATEADD(Calendar[Dates], -3, DAX).

My problem is that I cannot seem to get the two conditions working together. Is it even possible to do something like this with a measure?:

```
Yesterdays Sales = 
   Var TueToFri = CALCULATE([Sales Amount], PREVIOUSDAY(Calendar[Date])
   Var Mon = CALCULATE([Sales Amount], DATEADD(Calendar[Date], -3, DAY)

   IF WEEKDAY(Calendar[Date]) = 1
      Return Mon,
   Return TueToFri
```

If not, do you have any other ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works for me:

```
    Sales Amount PD = 
IF (
    WEEKDAY ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Calendar[Date] ) ) = 2;
    //Monday
    CALCULATE (
        [Sales Amount];
        DATEADD ( Calendar[Date]; -3; DAY )
    );
    IF (
        WEEKDAY ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Calendar[Date] ) ) = 1;
        //Sunday;
        BLANK ();
        IF (
            WEEKDAY ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Calendar[Date] ) ) = 7;
            //Saturday;
            BLANK ();
            CALCULATE (
                [Sales Amount];
                PREVIOUSDAY ( Calendar[Date] )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I believe the problem was caused by the calendar table returning multiple values. By using SELECTEDVALUE() only one date is returned, which can be used to do the comparision required.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
Yesterday Sales =
VAR Mon = CALCULATE([Sales Amount], DATEADD(Calendar[Date], -3, DAY)
VAR TueToFri = CALCULATE([Sales Amount], PREVIOUSDAY(Calendar[Date])
VAR SatSun = BLANK()

RETURN
IF(
  WEEKDAY(SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Date]), 2) = 1;
  Mon;
  IF(
    WEEKDAY(SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Date]), 2) >= 6;
    SatSun;
    TueToFri
  )
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I run into the same problem I had: The IF(WEEKDAY()) part will not let me select my calendar table. I believe this happens, because my calendar table would return multiple dates. However, I have managed to fix it in the meantime (see answer). Thanks again

Comment: I edited my solution to include an aggregation function for Calendar[Date]